# haskell Data.Aeson.Value to Text

Tags: haskell

```
data User = User { city :: Text
                 , country :: Text
                 , phone :: Text
                 , email :: Text}

instance ToJSON User where
    toJSON (User a b c d)= object ["a" .= a
                                  ,"b" .= b
                                  ,"c" .= c
                                  ,"d" .= d]

test:: User -> IO Value
test u = do
    let j = toJSON u
    return j
```

What I want is Text like so

```
test::User -> IO Text
test u = do
    let j = pack ("{\"city\":\"test\",\"country\":\"test\",\"phone\":\"test\",\"email\":\"test\"}")
    return j
```

I can't figure it out how to go from Value to Text

Comment: I don't think I understand the question but don't you want `Data.Text.Lazy.Builder.toLazyText . Data.Aeson.Encode.fromValue`?

Comment: What I want to achieve is `test :: User -> IO Text` where my data is converted to Text. Output of both test should be identical.

Comment: Builder is new for me, is there a strict builder for Text?

Comment: Couldn't match expected type `Text` with actual type `Data.Text.Lazy.Internal.Text`

Comment: Anyway, strict text builder doesn't make sense. You can convert lazy text to strict with `Data.Text.Lazy.toStrict`.

Comment: I use websocket sendTextData to send my json, I assume it only accepts strikt Text?

Comment: Do you know how to read haddock [documents](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/websockets/latest/doc/html/Network-WebSockets.html#v:sendTextData)?  `sendTextData` is polymorphic.  [It appears](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/websockets/latest/doc/html/Network-WebSockets.html#t:WebSocketsData) that Lazy and Strict ByteStrings and Text are all instances.

Comment: Also, isn't this (parsing a `Value` into `Text` or other types) exactly what `fromJSON` is for?

Comment: It wil get me a `fromJSON :: FromJSON a => Value -> Result a` How can you go from Result to Text and would it be better to do so?

Comment: As [the documentation shows](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson/0.6.0.2/doc/html/Data-Aeson.html#t:Result), `Result` is just a data type and you can pattern match against it (via `case` or a function argument pattern match) to get the `Error` or the successful parse of your `Text` value.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, nope, `fromJSON` isn't what you're looking for. It is used for deserializing JSON values, so the `FromJSON` instance for `Text` only parses `String "a JSON String" :: Value`, in other words: not at all what you are looking for. The `fromValue` function is the way to go.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is more difficult to do this than it should be for what (I think) is a generally useful function. `Data.Aeson.Encode.encode` does too much work and converts it all the way to a `ByteString`.

Starting with `encode` and switching the `Lazy.Text -> ByteString` to `Lazy.Text -> Strict.Text` conversion does what you want:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Text (encodeToTextBuilder)
import Data.Text
import Data.Text.Lazy (toStrict)
import Data.Text.Lazy.Builder (toLazyText)


data User = User
  { city    :: Text
  , country :: Text
  , phone   :: Text
  , email   :: Text
  }

instance ToJSON User where
  toJSON (User a b c d) = object
    [ "city"    .= a
    , "country" .= b
    , "phone"   .= c
    , "email"   .= d
    ]

test :: User -> Text
test = toStrict . toLazyText . encodeToTextBuilder . toJSON
```

Comment: You meant to say `import Data.Aeson.Encode (encodeToTextBuilder)`, I think.

Comment: it's 2022 and `Data.Aeson.Encode` is deprecated. use `import Data.Aeson.Text (encodeToTextBuilder)` instead

Answer (score 1):

Per Thomas' comment: you don't go from `Value` to `Text`, you go from `Value` to `ByteString`. The `sendTextData` function is polymorphic enough to accept `ByteString`s.